# How to save timestamp with timezone

Tags: java, sql-server, postgresql, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

My Project support Postgres and SQLServer DB.
I have a timestamp with a timezone column in my table x.
When I save timestamp value in the DB. I'm getting  as "2022-07-01 00:00:00.000000 +05:30" in the Postgres but in SQL server it is saving as "2022-07-01 00:00:00.000000 +00:00".
Can someone help me on how to get the value as Postgres in SQL server also?
Here is my java code

```
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss");
   Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("20220701T00:00:00") //this value comes as argument for this method. 
   return new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
```

Comment: It means the server timezone's are set differently. In Postgres you can find that by doing `SHOW TimeZone;` Have no idea how you find that out in SQL Server.

Comment: Don't use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Use `OffsetDateTime` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Also it seems to me that your unexpected result comes from incorrect use of those old classes. It's so easy to use them wrong, so just stop trying.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm getting as "2022-07-01 00:00:00.000000 +05:30" in the Postgres

No, you’re not.

A `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column in Postgres stores its values “in UTC”, meaning an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Any time zone or offset supplied with an input is used to adjust to UTC, then discarded. So every value read from that column will be in UTC, **always in UTC**.

Unfortunately, some tools and middleware have the anti-feature of applying a current default time zone to the retrieved value. [*pgAdmin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#pgAdmin) is one such tool, I’m sad to report.

Another problem is that the `toString` method of `java.util.Date` also has the same anti-feature, applying the JVM’s current default time zone.

Fortunately, the terrible `Date` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. JDBC 4.2 and later requires support for *java.time*. No need to ever use `Date`, `Calendar`, and `Timestamp`.

To retrieve a value from a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column, use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

You’ll see that object has an offset of zero, the true value stored in Postgres.

To write:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

As for your input string, it lacks an indicator of time zone or offset. So parse as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss" ) ;
String input = "20220701T00:00:00" ; 
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Now assign the intended time zone or offset to get a `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` respectively. I’ll assume you intend an offset of zero, represented by the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

---

I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about proper use of standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Your input string `"20220701T00:00:00"` is mixing the full “expanded” format for the time-of-day portion with its COLON characters alongside the abbreviated “basic” format for the date portion.

Use either the *expanded* version of ISO 8601, or the *basic*, but don't mix the two.

| Basic ISO 8601 | Expanded ISO 8601 |
| --- | --- |
| 20220701T000000 | 2022-07-01T00:00:00 |

I recommend sticking with the full expanded format.

And if the publisher of that data intended an offset of zero, they should say so. Append a `Z`, pronounced *Zulu*. Or append `+00:00`, though I’d recommend the `Z`.

> 2022-07-01T00:00:00Z

---

All this has been covered many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: Thank you Basil Bourque. Will try to learn more on this.